# Decompiling MCP on 1.8.8

Tags: java, minecraft, decompiling

When I run decompile.bat on MCP 1.8.8 it gives me this error:

link : https://justpaste.it/7qu4i

I'm trying to make a client on version 1.8.8.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question, I think it needs *"debugging details"*. Please consider the guidelines in the help center [*"How do I ask a good question?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when decompiling MCP , you encounter an error with `Cartesian.java`, shown in this screenshot. The solution to this is going to line 73 in `Cartesian.java` and changing the line from:

```java
return (Iterator<T[]>)(this.iterables.length <= 0 ? Collections.singletonList((Object[])Cartesian.createArray(this.clazz, 0)).iterator() : new Cartesian.Product.ProductIterator(this.clazz, this.iterables));
```

To:

```java
return (Iterator)(this.iterables.length <= 0 ? Collections.singletonList((Object[])Cartesian.createArray(this.clazz, 0)).iterator() : new Cartesian.Product.ProductIterator(this.clazz, this.iterables));
```